# How to Have an Imported Rectangular Image be Displayed as a Parallelogram with LaTeX

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I would like to be able to call in a rectangular image into Latex and have it appear as a parallelogram instead of a rectangle.

For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}    
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

produces the rectangular image

[image]

QUESTION: How may I have it appear as a parallelogram inclined slightly to the right (say, base angles 85 degrees and 95 degrees, respectively) with the lengths of the corresponding sides the same as that of the rectangle?

Something like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188) help? The `\slantbox` will give a parallelogram with `width` as the base and `height` as the vertical height, not the side length.

Comment: @Willoughby I had looked at that before posting my question. However, it seems that  the answers are not directly related to a pre-existing image; but rather, for instance, one that is being produced  on the spot. But thank you for your comment.

Comment: @mlchristians  would u like to add a hand sketch of the desired output

Comment: @Willoughby I just modified the question to include a hand-drawn sketch. Thank you.

Comment: @Willoughby's link has [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326144/119), the second example of which involves loading an external image (in png format) and slanting it using TikZ.

Comment: @Willie Wong Thank you for pointing out the second example which imports an external image. I am unfamiliar with much of the syntax---but have begun to play around with it to see what it does.

Comment: Yes. My comment was generated automatically because I voted to close the question because it's a potential duplicate. Sorry for the confusion.