# What is this capital-beta-shaped symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, chemistry

I'm looking for a symbol from this equation (for buffer capacity of solution):

[image]

It looks like a capital beta to me or a capital Eszett letter from the German alphabet. However, to my knowledge, the capital beta should look like "B" and there is no German word starting with Eszett. This symbol is definitely not beta, since it's also used in a different equation:
[image]

Please, help to identify.

P.S. If needed: article with equations is [Understanding, deriving and Computing Buffer Capacity](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed077p1640) by Edward T. Urbansky and Michael R. Schock

**Update 1:** As suggested in comments: I added `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` and called `\mathscr{B}` Result is :

[image]

Close, but not exactly what I need.

Close enough **solution**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% here as scr use either: rsfso, boondoxo
% no luck using mathpi ((
\usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \mathscr{B}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\mathscr{B}`... though you need a math font with the `\mathscr` variant defined. (E.g. `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`.)

Comment: @WillieWong Tried, see updates in post. Close, but not close enough.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of the `mathalfa` package it's quite close to the calligraphic letters of the `mathpi` font, but that's a comercial font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a B from Mathpi script. However, as pointed out by @WillieWong, this font is commercial.

However, the B from the upright version of Boondox script seems to be a very close approximation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxupr]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\( \mathscr{B} \)
\end{document}
```

In case you can access the Mathpi font, the last example should output the exact same B as in your example if you replace the option `boondoxupr` with `mathpi`.

Comment: Nice! However, the `boondoxo` is closer to desired shape. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using pdflatex, you can apply an unslant to the character ([Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][\slantvalue]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\newcommand\mathscrup[2][-.4]{\mkern2mu
 \slantbox[#1]{$\mathscr{#2}$}\mkern-2mu}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{B}$ normal

$\mathscrup{B}$ unslanted

$x\mathscrup{BL}x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The specific version that your screen cap shows is most likely from the *commercial* Adobe Mathematical Pi collection of fonts.

If you don't have it, and want something that looks more upright than the `rsfs` version, try [rsfso](https://ctan.org/pkg/rsfso).