# Strikethrough rows and columns in matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, arrays, strikeout

I've found this code from [How to cross a row in matrix with a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42639/how-to-cross-a-row-in-matrix-with-a-line)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\pmark}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\node(#1)at (-1em,.7ex){};\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\smark}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\draw(#1)--(0,.7ex);\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{array}{cccc|c}
a&b&bc&d&f\\\hline
0\pmark{a}&0&1&1&1\smark{a}\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1&1\\
\end{array}$$
\end{document}
```

It works like a charm for rows but the lines are quite skewed. Can someone see how to fix this to work for both rows and columns?

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196258/draw-a-vertical-line-over-the-entries-of-a-column-in-an-array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, try this may be it help you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\pmark}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\node(#1)at (-1em,.7ex){};\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\smark}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\draw(#1)--(0,.7ex);\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\vpmark}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\node(#1)at (.3em,5ex){};\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\vsmark}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\draw(#1)--(.3em,-1ex);\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
a&b&bc&d&f\\\hline
0\pmark{a}&0&\vpmark{b}1&1&1\smark{a}\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&\vsmark{b}1&1&1\\
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```