# Creating an Elimination Matrix with strikethrough rows/columns

Tags: formatting, matrices, strikeout

I am writing a paper, and I need to display an elimination matrix during the steps of finding a determinant.

```
\[
A =\begin {bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22}
    \end {bmatrix}
\]
```

The above gives me a bracketed `2 x 2` Matrix. What I need to do, is display a subsequent elimination matrix where the ith row and jth column is lined out. I need to line out any row and any column I desire.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but what exactly is your question? I don't know what isn't working for you, or what exactly you want it to look like.

Comment: Apparently you have two accounts -- please contact the SE staff to get the accounts merged. And I think your question is off-topic

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't really think this is about MathJax. HappyS5: Math isn't rendered by MathJax here, see [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272) If you want to show the output of something you have to take a screenshot of the PDF and upload that. Hence, you might as well edit away all the comments about that, it only leads to confusion.

Comment: And by the way, see if [Striking out matrix lines and columns: is Tikz the only way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277375) is of help.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235599/strikethrough-rows-and-columns-in-matrices?rq=1