# Striking out matrix lines and columns: is Tikz the only way?

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

I would like to show a matrix with "strike-out lines" on some of its rows and columns. After some research I found a solution using Tikz matrices, which I reproduce here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \matrix (mat) [%
       matrix of nodes,
       left delimiter={(},right delimiter={)}
     ]
      {%
        2 & 6 & 0 & 4\\
        3 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
      };
    % do the strike out thing
      \draw[black] (mat-1-1.west)  -- (mat-1-4.east);
      \draw[black] (mat-1-3.north) -- (mat-4-3.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        3 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: document]

However, there are a few problems with that: first, the alignment with the second matrix is obviously wrong. Also, the two matrices are in different styles (row/column distance, font, etc).

I already have a several-hundred-long document, so switching every matrix from LateX matrix to Tikz matrix would be too time-comsuming. Is there any other way to get the strike-out effect, resulting in a matrix whose style is consistent with the rest of the matrices in the document?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `tikzmark` and overlay the TikZ code on your existing matrices.

Comment: In http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26909/86 I wrote some code that replaced AMS matrices with TikZ matrices without changing their use.  I don't know if it still works ...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method which uses no big graphics engine with many libraries and dependencies.

1. it uses the `pdftex` `\pdfsavepos` primitive, also available in `xetex`.
2. it uses the LaTeX `picture` environment to draw the lines at shipout time, with the help of package [eso-pic](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) which transforms each page into a LaTeX picture. I observed some conflict with `xetex` (shifted vertical locations) which is miraculously fixed by using package `geometry` (I have no explication).
3. as the `\line` command of the Leslie Lamport `picture` environment is quite limited, I used the `pict2e` environment which has a more powerful `\Line`. Any package enhancing the `picture` environment would do. In particular it seems I don't know how to do dashed lines with `pict2e`.

It is very easy to change the code to

a. replace `pict2e` with some other picture environment enhancing package,

b. replace `eso-pic` with any package allowing to draw in absolute coordinates on the page.

Thus this is a very low-weight solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

% matrices
\usepackage{amsmath}

% I discovered a bad interaction of eso-pic with xetex
% which is fixed for an unknown reason to me by loading
% package geometry
\usepackage{geometry}

% transforms the page into a LaTeX picture
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% enhances original LaTeX picture
% there are other packages
% unfortunately I don't know how to draw dashed lines with pict2e
\usepackage{pict2e}

% for some color
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\newbox\JayBox
\def\JayNodeCount{0}%

\def\zapspaces #1 #2{#1#2\zapspaces }

\newcommand\Node [2]{%
% make the code work also if no amsmath
    \ifcsname ifmeasuring@\endcsname
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\unless\ifmeasuring@}\iftrue
      \xdef\JayNodeCount{\the\numexpr\JayNodeCount+\@ne}%
      \ifcsname JAY@nodecoords@\romannumeral\JayNodeCount\endcsname
        \global
        \expandafter\let
        \csname JAY@nodename@\expandafter\zapspaces\detokenize{#1} \@gobble
        \expandafter\endcsname
        \csname JAY@nodecoords@\romannumeral\JayNodeCount\endcsname
      \else\typeout{========> New JAY node: run LaTeX again ! <========}%
      \fi
         \sbox\JayBox{$\m@th #2$}%
      \pdfsavepos
         \edef\JAY@temp{%
              \global
              \def\@backslashchar
                          JAY@nodecoords@\romannumeral\JayNodeCount
                  {{\noexpand\the\numexpr\pdflastxpos+\number\wd\JayBox/2}%
                   {\noexpand\the\numexpr\pdflastypos+\number\ht\JayBox/2}%
                   {\number\wd\JayBox/2}{\number\ht\JayBox/2}}%
                       }%
         \write\@mainaux\expandafter{\JAY@temp}%
    \fi
    #2%
}%

\def\JAY@north{north}
\def\JAY@south{south}
\def\JAY@west {west}
\def\JAY@east {east}
\def\JAY@northwest{northwest}
\def\JAY@northeast{northeast}
\def\JAY@southeast{southeast}
\def\JAY@southwest{southwest}


\def\JAY@setupAnode #1#2#3#4%
{%
    \def\JAY@Ax {#1}\def\JAY@Ay {#2}\def\JAY@Adx {#3}\def\JAY@Ady {#4}%
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@north\edef\JAY@Ay {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ay+\JAY@Ady}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@south\edef\JAY@Ay {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ay-\JAY@Ady}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@west \edef\JAY@Ax {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ax-\JAY@Adx}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@east \edef\JAY@Ax {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ax+\JAY@Adx}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@northwest
                   \edef\JAY@Ay {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ay+\JAY@Ady}%
                   \edef\JAY@Ax {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ax-\JAY@Adx}%
    \fi
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@northeast
                   \edef\JAY@Ay {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ay+\JAY@Ady}%
                   \edef\JAY@Ax {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ax+\JAY@Adx}%
    \fi
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@southeast
                   \edef\JAY@Ay {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ay-\JAY@Ady}%
                   \edef\JAY@Ax {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ax+\JAY@Adx}%
    \fi
    \ifx\JAY@Aspec\JAY@southwest
                   \edef\JAY@Ay {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ay-\JAY@Ady}%
                   \edef\JAY@Ax {\the\numexpr\JAY@Ax-\JAY@Adx}%
    \fi
}%

\def\JAY@setupBnode #1#2#3#4%
{%
    \def\JAY@Bx {#1}\def\JAY@By {#2}\def\JAY@Bdx {#3}\def\JAY@Bdy {#4}%
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@north\edef\JAY@By {\the\numexpr\JAY@By+\JAY@Bdy}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@south\edef\JAY@By {\the\numexpr\JAY@By-\JAY@Bdy}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@west \edef\JAY@Bx {\the\numexpr\JAY@Bx-\JAY@Bdx}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@east \edef\JAY@Bx {\the\numexpr\JAY@Bx+\JAY@Bdx}\fi
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@northwest
                   \edef\JAY@By {\the\numexpr\JAY@By+\JAY@Bdy}%
                   \edef\JAY@Bx {\the\numexpr\JAY@Bx-\JAY@Bdx}%
    \fi
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@northeast
                   \edef\JAY@By {\the\numexpr\JAY@By+\JAY@Bdy}%
                   \edef\JAY@Bx {\the\numexpr\JAY@Bx+\JAY@Bdx}%
    \fi
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@southeast
                   \edef\JAY@By {\the\numexpr\JAY@By-\JAY@Bdy}%
                   \edef\JAY@Bx {\the\numexpr\JAY@Bx+\JAY@Bdx}%
    \fi
    \ifx\JAY@Bspec\JAY@southwest
                   \edef\JAY@By {\the\numexpr\JAY@By-\JAY@Bdy}%
                   \edef\JAY@Bx {\the\numexpr\JAY@Bx-\JAY@Bdx}%
    \fi
}%

\newcommand\NodeLine [2][]{\def\JAY@opt{#1}\JAY@NodeLine #2\JAY@NodeLine}

\def\JAY@NodeLine #1[#2]#3->#4[#5]#6\JAY@NodeLine
{%
    \edef\JAY@nodeA {\expandafter\zapspaces\detokenize{#1} \@gobble}%
    \edef\JAY@nodeB {\expandafter\zapspaces\detokenize{#4} \@gobble}%
    \let\JAY@temp\empty
    \ifcsname JAY@nodename@\JAY@nodeA\endcsname
    \ifcsname JAY@nodename@\JAY@nodeB\endcsname
       \edef\JAY@Aspec {\zapspaces #2 \@gobble}%
       \edef\JAY@Bspec {\zapspaces #5 \@gobble}%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            \JAY@setupAnode\csname JAY@nodename@\JAY@nodeA\endcsname
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
            \JAY@setupBnode\csname JAY@nodename@\JAY@nodeB\endcsname
    \edef\JAY@temp {%
     \noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
% THIS IS THE ONLY PLACE WHERE THE PICTURE SYNTAX IS USED
% here we use \Line from package pict2e
% The optional argument to \NodeLine contains optional commands
       {\setlength{\unitlength}{1sp}%
       \linethickness{1pt}%
       \unexpanded\expandafter{\JAY@opt}%
       \noexpand\Line (\JAY@Ax,\JAY@Ay)(\JAY@Bx,\JAY@By)%
                   }}}%
    \fi\fi
  \JAY@temp
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
        \Node{B}{2} & 6 & \Node{C}{0} & \Node{E}{4}\\
        3 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & \Node{D}{1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        3 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\]

% No need to be inside the display, but
% make sure to issue these commands on the same page !
\NodeLine[\color{blue}]{B[west] -> E[east]}
\NodeLine[\color{red}] {C[north]-> D[south]}

%\begin{center}
%TWO COMPILATIONS NEEDED\\
%AFTER EACH NODE INSERTION\\
%OR ANY EXTRA (VERTICAL)\\ MATERIAL ON THE PAGE
%\end{center}


\[
\begin{pmatrix}
        \Node{A}{2} & 6 & 0 & 4\\
        3 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
        \Node{B}{5} & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & \Node{C}{0}\\
        3 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & 0 & \Node{D}{0}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

% unfortunately I don't know how to draw dashed lines with pict2e

\NodeLine[\color{green}\linethickness{2pt}]{ A [north west] -> D [south east]}
\NodeLine[\color{green}\linethickness{2pt}]{ B [south west] -> C [north east]}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: striked outs lines and columns with no TikZ]

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple with `pstricks`:  put the ordinary content of your equation in a `pspicture` environment, insert a node at the beginning and end of a row or column, and connect these nodes at the end of the `pspicture` environment.

With the `auto-pst-pdf` package, it can be compiled with `pdflatex`, provided you set the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX) for the compiler.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pspicture}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \rnode{B}{2} & 6 & \rnode{C}{0} & \rnode{E}{4}\\
        3 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & \rnode{D}{1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        3 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\psset{nodesep=-1.5ex, linewidth=0.4pt}
\ncline{B}{E}\ncline[nodesep=-2ex]{C}{D}
\end{pspicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here, I `\stackinset` 2 rules over top of the `pmatrix`.  The syntax is

`\stackinset{H-anchor}{H-offset}{V-anchor}{V-offset}{inset}{base-image}`

Below is the MWE, in which I nest two insets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{1.6\baselineskip}{\rule{4.4\baselineskip}{.4pt}}{%
\stackinset{c}{.61\baselineskip}{c}{}{\rule{.4pt}{4.0\baselineskip}}{%
\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 6 & 0 & 4\\
        3 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        3 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
        5 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{pmatrix}` (of `amsmath`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, columns and rows. Then you can draw whatever rule you want with a Tikz instruction but using those nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  2 & 6 & 0 & 4\\
  3 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
  5 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
\CodeAfter \tikz [blue] \draw (1.5-|1) -- (1.5-|last) (1-|3.5) -- (last-|3.5) ;
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  3 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
  5 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]